# How to add navigationOptions to a memoized react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation, flowtype

I'm using flow types and have a memo wrapped functional component, however when trying to assign navigationOptions for react-navigation, flow is just going haywire:

On my component

```js
const navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({}) // more stuff

const Foo = memo((props: IProps) => {
...
})

/*
Here it breaks down
Cannot assign `navigationOptions` to `Foo['navigation...']` because property `navigationOptions` is missing in  `React.AbstractComponentStatics`
*/
Foo.navigationOptions = navigationOptions
export default Foo
```

Even if I type cast it to any, and then try to use it on my router:

```js
/*
Cannot call `createStackNavigator` with object literal bound to `routeConfigMap` because in property `Foo.screen`: Either property `navigationOptions` is missing in  AbstractComponent [1] but exists in  `withOptionalNavigationOptions` [2]. Or property `router` is missing in  AbstractComponent [1] but exists in  `withRouter` [3].Flow(InferError)
*/
const FooStack = createStackNavigator({
  Foo: { screen: FooScreen }
}, stackNavOptions)
```

How am I supposed to properly apply types here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour. If you actually check `React$AbstractComponentStatics` you'll see that there are very few allowed properties, such as `displayName` which is valid. They've even removed propTypes which even though it's valid it's not encouraged which is why it has been removed.

To get around this you can use a suppression comments to mark it as a false positive,

```
// $FlowExpectedError navigationOptions
Foo.navigationOptions = navigationOptions
```

Flow supports `$FlowFixMe` and as of version 0.125.0, `$FlowIssue` and `$FlowExpectedError` by default to suppress errors.